# Sync Google spreadsheet in Cartodb

Tags: carto

I would like to syncronize a Google spreadsheet in my account in the CartoDB.com service, but the sync options are not available. I have found this in the documentation of Cartodb, but I have no experience in programming, and I do not know how to run a rake task. 
[image: documentation screenshot]

Is there any other thing that I should do to sync the tables?

Comment: Are you working in cartodb.com or in your own CartoDB installation?

Comment: I am working in Cartodb.com. Do I have to install CartoDB to sync tables?

Answer (score 2):

Sync Tables in CartoDB.com are a feature included with some of their paid plans. Free accounts do not include this feature, so you won't be able to have Sync Tables in CartoDB.com unless your user plan has this feature enabled.

The documentation you are referring to in your question is related with the Open Source CartoDB project which people can install in their own servers by following the instructions in the CartoDB repository: https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb. In this scenario, system administrators have to run a Rake task in the server in order to trigger the synchronization of already connected tables, but this doesn't apply to the SaaS in CartoDB.com in which you are working.

Comment: I do not have my own server, so I am afraid that I will not be able to install CartoDB. Thank you very much for your answer. You have saved me a lot of time..